# Refactor using a JavaScript generator

Tags: javascript

I have the following working code:

```js
const nextElem = document.getElementById('next');
nextElem.addEventListener('click', renderNextProfile);

let profiles;
window.onload = refillProfiles;

async function refillProfiles() {
  let data = await fetchProfiles(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5`);
  profiles = data.results;
}

async function fetchProfiles(url) {
  try {
    let profiles = await fetch(url);
    return profiles.json();
  } catch {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

function renderNextProfile() {
  if (profiles.length) {
    let profile = profiles.shift();
    console.log(profile.name.first);
  } else {
    refillProfiles();
  }
}
```

Once the page loads, makes a request of 5 profiles to the [randomuser.me](http://randomuser.me) api. Then a button triggers an event handler that consumes items from an array and logs them to the console. Once the array is empty, a new call to `refillProfiles` is made.
I would like to know if I could refactor `refillProfiles` using a **generator** so that when the **generator** is exhausted, `refillProfiles` is called again.

This seems to work, but on the **sixth** profile, I have to click twice to get the next five:

```js
const nextElem = document.getElementById('next');
nextElem.addEventListener('click', renderNextProfile);

let profiles;
let profileGenerator;

window.onload = refillProfiles;

async function refillProfiles() {
  let data = await fetchProfiles(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5`);
  profiles = data.results;
  profileGenerator = createProfileGenerator(profiles);
}

async function fetchProfiles(url) {
  try {
    let profiles = await fetch(url);
    return profiles.json();
  } catch {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

function renderNextProfile() {
  let profile = profileGenerator.next();
  if (!profile.done) {
    console.log(profile.value.name.first);
  } else {
    refillProfiles();
  }
}

function *createProfileGenerator(profiles) {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < profiles.length) {
    yield profiles[i];
    i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to fix almost everything. The only thing that doesn't work great is that the image loads after the profile, and for half a second doesn't show up. I would appreciate ideas regarding how to make profile info and image changing at the same time:

```js
const nextElem            = document.getElementById('next');
const imageDisplayElem    = document.getElementById('image-display');
const profileDisplayElem  = document.getElementById('profile-display');
const userNameElem        = document.getElementById('username');

nextElem.addEventListener('click', nextProfile);

let profiles;
let profileGenerator;

window.onload = firstProfile;

async function firstProfile() {
  await refillProfiles();
  nextProfile();
}

async function refillProfiles() {
  let data = await fetchProfiles(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5`);
  profiles = data.results;
  profileGenerator = createProfileGenerator(profiles);
}

async function fetchProfiles(url) {
  const data = await fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok)
        throw new Error("Response not OK!");
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(`Network error: ${error.message}`));
  return data;
}

function nextProfile() {
  let profile = profileGenerator.next();
  if (profile.done) {
    // console.log(profile.value.name.first);
    renderNextProfile(profile.value);
    refillProfiles();
  } else {
    // console.log(profile.value.name.first);
    renderNextProfile(profile.value);
  }
}

function renderNextProfile(profile) {
  let imageSource = profile.picture.large;
  let name        = profile.name.first;
  let gender      = profile.gender;
  let age         = profile.dob.age;
  let username    = profile.login.username;
  let city        = profile.location.city;
  let state       = profile.location.state;
  let country     = profile.location.country;

  profileDisplayElem.innerHTML = `\
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Name: ${name}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Gender: ${gender}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">City: ${city} (${state})</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Country: ${country}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Age: ${age}</li>
  </ul>`;
  imageDisplayElem.innerHTML = `<img src="${imageSource}">`;
  userNameElem.innerText = username;
  
}

function *createProfileGenerator(profiles) {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < profiles.length) {
    if (i == profiles.length - 1) {
      return profiles[i];
    } else {
      yield profiles[i];
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```js
const nextElem = document.getElementById('next');
nextElem.addEventListener('click', renderNextProfile);

async function fetchProfiles() {
  const data = await fetchJSON(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5`);
  return data.results;
}

async function fetchJSON(url) {
  const resp = await fetch(url);
  if(!resp.ok)
    throw new Error(`Fetch from ${url} failed with HTTP status ${resp.status}`);
  return resp.json();
}

async function* getProfiles() {
  while(true){
    yield* await fetchProfiles();
  }
}

const profiles = getProfiles();

async function renderNextProfile(){
  const {value: nextProfile} = await profiles.next();

  console.log(nextProfile.name.first);
}
```

```html
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Note that I've changed several things about your code.

I've renamed `fetchProfiles` to `fetchJSON`, as all it does is fetching JSON. I've added a check to `response.ok`, omitting that is a common pitfall of `fetch`.

I've also removed the `try..catch` from there, so the code will now crash if there's a network error (note that yours would do that too, just with a more cryptic error message after logging the real error). You might want to implement a retrying logic somewhere.

The generator part is truly easy: just loops forever, and for each iteration, fetches the profiles, then `yield`s them one-by-one.

Comment: That was great advice regarding fetch. Spent some minutes reading about it (now I know the difference between network errors and HTTP errors) 
Check my updated function. Now it's checking for both type of errors.

Comment: Any idea about how to synchronize the load of the image with the load of the profile info?